# React - Query Parameters Are Empty on Page Load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having an issue with navigation logic in React, and it'd be amazing to get some help.

I have front-end web app written in TypeScript, React and Ionic Framework V5.

The app has a fairly standard search box that redirects to a results page with the location `/search?query={query here}`.

When I hit the search button, the navigation is handled by React Router. I am redirected to the results page & the search query appears in the browser's address bar, but the query string is empty when it is fetched in the functional component logic - giving me incorrect search results.

The search box routes to the results page like so:

```
<IonButton fill="clear" className="search-button" routerLink={`/search?query=${searchValue}`}>
  <IonIcon name="search-outline" />
</IonButton>
```

- Note that the `routerLink` property is simply an Ionic helper for React Router, the problem is the same if I encapsulate the button in a normal `<Link/>` tag.

On the search page, the query string is read like so:

```
const Home: React.FC<SimplePageProps> = ({ axios }) => {
  const queryParams = useQuery();
  const param = queryParams.get('query');

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/products?query=${param}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const data = camelcaseKeys(response.data, { deep: true });
        setProducts(data.items.map((product: Product) => (
          <IonCol key={product.id} size-md="4" size-xl="3">
            <ProductCard product={product} />
          </IonCol>
        )));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // TODO show error element
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [axios, param]);
```

As mentioned, the query string is empty when it is fetched in the functional component logic - giving me incorrect search results. When I refresh the page, the query string is not empty and the search results appear. Any ideas?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you might have more than 1 router running in your app. Can you share complete code? Also, what is `useQuery`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `useQuery` is the helper hook described here: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sleeping on it & some more searching, I managed to fix this.

My solution was to strip things back to a vanilla JavaScript command, `window.location.search`. This always fetches the correct query parameters from the URL, whereas the React Router helper hooks would be `undefined` when first routed to the page.

`useLocation()` is included so that when another search is performed from the results page, the React component re-renders to reflect the new query string.

```
const Home: React.FC<SimplePageProps> = ({ axios }) => {
  // parse query string parameter
  const { search } = window.location;
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search).get('query');

  useLocation(); // including this forces a re-render when the URL changes

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/products?query=${query}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const data = camelcaseKeys(response.data, { deep: true });
        setProducts(data.items.map((product: Product) => (
          <IonCol key={product.id} size-md="4" size-xl="3">
            <ProductCard product={product} />
          </IonCol>
        )));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // TODO show error element
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [axios, query]);
```